# python - Find "hidden" links with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I want to take links of the games from a page such as [this](https://www.soccer24.com/italy/serie-a/results/) but when I try to find the links of the games there isn't an href attribute, but only a title attribute "Click for match detail!". How can I find the links? I tried to disable Javascript or use Selenium, but without result.

Comment: show your code, what did you try i we will help

Comment: It looks like those are just table rows with a click handler, the base url is probably defined somewhere in JS and the rest of the info encoded into the specific rows attributes

Comment: Sorry I'm new with python. I don't have code, because I do not know where I have to look. Yes, the url is probably somewhere in JS...but how do I find this link?

Comment: I suggest using your browser dev tools (on Chrome and Firefox, usually F12) to browse the table rows / cells for tag, id and class names which could be useful later, and for assigned event listeners. Then browse for script tags which will guide you to the JS.